# How can I make a LEGO heroica scale fountain of youth using bricks from Fortaan or Waldurk?

Tags: building, heroica

I have started collecting heroica and I thought "wouldn't a fountain of youth be superb!" but I only have Fortaan and Waldurk... any ideas?

Comment: Is that all the LEGO you've got, or are there other pieces to work with?

Comment: @Miles, Zhaph - Ben Duguid is right.  You need to supply more information if you want an answer.  Are those Heroica sets all the Legos that you have?  Do you have more, but not want to use them?  Please clarify.

Comment: The way I read the question, it does imply "only parts from these sets". If not, it would just be formulated "How can I make a LEGO Heroica scale fountain of youth?". Not everybody has a huge stash of LEGO parts, and we won't shy away from a challenge, will we? (well, I suppose I will since, I don't have any of the two :-/)

Answer (score 6):

Thought I'd finally step up to the plate - here's my first attempt.

On the basis that the Fountain of Youth is probably an end goal rather than something you'd come across on the way somewhere else I've gone for an 8x8 base, but as we're limited to these two sets I've had to go with grey - I could probably have gone with the 4x4 blue plates, but felt that might limit other options, and wanted the figures to be able to move around the fountain a bit.

I've added the goblet as a collectable treasure that could have a "healing" rule for use in campaigns:

[image: Complete Fountain]

[image: Exploded View]